# Site not available with gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi

Tags: python, django, deployment, gunicorn

I'm new to deployment, when I run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I am able to access it on domain and **IP** with **HTTP**

but when I run

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 core.wsgi
```

I tried to test it by running

```
wget http:server_ip:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000
```

its just stuck on following message

> Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
>
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

result from following command

```
sudo ufw status
```

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: When you run using `gunicorn` are you able to access it on browser using your public IP?

Comment: thanks for responding but this is solved, the issue was that i had hsts setting on in django settings.py and my browser was changing http to https which my site could serve i guess this was issue, i also changed to uwsgi, now i can view it with my domain or port 8000 with http